# ¿Por qué Swagger muestra error: "should NOT have additional properties"?

Tags: swagger

Estoy aprendiendo y practicando con Swagger. Al definir los parámetros para una ruta, me muestra el siguiente error:

> Structural error at paths./autores/{id}/books/{idBook}.get.parameters.0
> should NOT have additional properties additionalProperty: descrption

Tengo definido otro endpoint similar uno arroja este error, sí en este path en particular. Dejo el código a continuación. El error, como informa Swagger, está en los parameters del get de:

`"/autores/{id}/books/{idBook}"`

Leí que los path params debían ser requeridos pero sigue sin solucionarse.

```
openapi: 3.0.0
servers:
  - description: ServidorLocal
    url: 'http://localhost:3000'
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Aplicacion de Escritores
  description: Documentación API Escritores
  contact: 
    name: Franco Fernandez
    email: fran.fercalderon@gmail.com
paths:
  /autores:
    get:
      tags:
        - Autores
      summary: Obtener listado de todos los autores.
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Listado de autores.
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Escritores'
  '/autores/{id}/books':
    get:
      summary: Bibliografía de un autor especifico
      tags:
        - Libros
      parameters:
        - name: id
          in: path
          required: true
          description: Id unico del autor
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Book'
        '404':
          description: Autor inexistente
  '/autores/{id}/books/{idBook}':
    get:
      summary: Obtener libro en específico
      tags:
        - Libros
      parameters:
        - name: idBook
          in: path
          required: true
          descrption: id del libro
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int32
        - name: id
          in: path
          required: true
          descrption: id del autor
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int32
      responses:
        '200':
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Book'
        '404':
          description: Libro inexistente
components:
  schemas:
    Escritores:
      type: object
      required:
        - name
        - lastname
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          format: int64
          example: 1
        name:
          type: string
          example: Joanne K 
        lastname:
          type: string
          example: Rowling
        dob:
          type: string
          format: date
          example: 04/09/1981
        books:
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Book'
    Book:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          format: int64
          example: 1
        title:
          type: string
          example: Harry Potter 
        description:
          type: string
          example: Fantasy Book
        publishYear:
          type: integer
          format: int64 
          example: 1998
```

Comment: A mi me resulto quitando el schema de los parámetros y dejando el type a la altura de los demas atributos, quedando algo asi: ```parameters:
        - name: id
          in: path
          required: true
          description: Id unico del autor
          type: string
```